# Regular IRQL_UNEXPECTED_VALUE bluescreens on windows 10

Tags: windows, wireless-networking, drivers, bsod

I recently updated my Dell Vostro 460 to windows 10. It ran fine for a while, but now I keep getting IRQL_UNEXPECTED_VALUE bluescreens.

The starting point for the BSODs might have been one of my routers malfunctioning (not being able to connect to the internet), although the other one works flawlessly.
According the bluescreenview, the BSOD was caused by nwifi.sys, with ndis.sys, ntoskrnl.exe and tcip.sys being involved as well.

Google led me to believe that the drivers for my DW1525 (802.11n) Wlan card are causing these crashes. I tried to update them, but the drivers from Dell can't be installed on windows 10 and the ones I got from DriverMax didn't work.

Can I fix the problem or is my only choice going back to windows 7? If it is, why did windows 10 work without problems at the beginning? Thanks to everybody answering - I am kind of puzzled atm.

Edit: It hasn't crashed for a few hours after I ran sfc /scannow in the CMD command prompt and my router decided to work again. Will keep this post updated.

Minidumps are here: http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=21528134954441516816

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff560202%28v=vs.85%29.aspx We need a dump file from C:\Windows\Minidump to see more details.

Comment: have you installed a new driver? Is he issue fixed?

Comment: Sorry for not replying earlier, the main problem is/was that the drivers were not available for windows 10, so the install failed. The card did work again though, I am not sure why, maybe because of sfc/scannow or because the router was functional again. Thank you very much for the help nonetheless!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the dump, the crash is caused by your WIFI adapter (Atheros driver):

```
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

IRQL_UNEXPECTED_VALUE (c8)
The processor's IRQL is not what it should be at this time.  This is
usually caused by a lower level routine changing IRQL for some period
and not restoring IRQL at the end of that period (eg acquires spinlock
but doesn't release it).
        if UniqueValue is 0 or 1
            2 = APC->KernelRoutine
            3 = APC
            4 = APC->NormalRoutine
Arguments:
Arg1: 0000000000000000, (Current IRQL << 16) | (Expected IRQL << 8) | UniqueValue
Arg2: 0000000000000002
Arg3: 0000000000000000
Arg4: 0000000000000000

Debugging Details:
------------------

*** WARNING: Unable to verify timestamp for athrx.sys
*** ERROR: Module load completed but symbols could not be loaded for athrx.sys

BIOS_DATE:  02/15/2011

BASEBOARD_PRODUCT:  0Y2MRG

BASEBOARD_VERSION:  A00

BUGCHECK_P1: 0

BUGCHECK_P2: 2

BUGCHECK_P3: 0

BUGCHECK_P4: 0

CPU_COUNT: 8

CPU_MHZ: d40

CPU_VENDOR:  GenuineIntel

CPU_FAMILY: 6

CPU_MODEL: 2a

CPU_STEPPING: 7

CUSTOMER_CRASH_COUNT:  1

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  WIN8_DRIVER_FAULT

BUGCHECK_STR:  0xC8

PROCESS_NAME:  System

CURRENT_IRQL:  2

ANALYSIS_VERSION: 10.0.10240.9 amd64fre

LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from fffff800071fe734 to fffff800071c1d00

STACK_TEXT:  
00 nt!KeBugCheckEx
01 nt! ?? ::FNODOBFM::`string'
02 tcpip!FlReceiveNetBufferListChain
03 ndis!ndisMIndicateNetBufferListsToOpen
04 ndis!ndisMTopReceiveNetBufferLists
05 ndis!ndisCallReceiveHandler
06 ndis!NdisMIndicateReceiveNetBufferLists
07 athrx
08 0x0
09 athrx
0a 0x0


IMAGE_NAME:  athrx.sys

    Loaded symbol image file: athrx.sys
    Image path: \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\athrx.sys
    Image name: athrx.sys
    Browse all global symbols  functions  data
    Timestamp:        Thu Jul 01 22:27:36 2010
```

Your driver is from 2010, [look for a newer driver](https://www.atheros.cz/atheros-wireless-drivers.html).